# Meteor app doesn't refresh automatically

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am extremely new to Meteor. I have started just now, after reading the initial documents and the screencast. After, creating the new app, I started to experiment with the sample hello world app. However, whenever I make any change in the JS or HTML file, it doesn't updates the browser automatically, but only after I manually refresh the page. Why so ?

I am using Mozilla Firefox 16.0 on Ubuntu 12.10 (64 bit)

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in the browser console? What about in the terminal running Meteor?

Comment: no errors ! neither in the console nor in the terminal :(

Comment: Have you tried `meteor reset`

Comment: tried meteor reset. Didn't help. Though, now I noticed that it works on other browsers perfectly. Somehow, the issue is only with firefox. I shall reinstall ff and see if it fixes.

Comment: same here my page does not refresh when i add new data in the database. Can  you please tell me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you allow cookies. I experienced the same when I did instructed cookie monster to only allow cookies for a session.
When fully allowing my domain, the refresh started working